# Binary (de)serialization library for c++

Tags: c++, serialization

A while ago I posted the code for this library I'm working on, and have refactored the code quite a bit ever since. I would appreciate any feedback in regards to what I have so far to see what can I improve still.
**binaryio/reader.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "binaryio/swap.h"

#ifndef BINARYIO_READER_H
#define BINARYIO_READER_H

namespace binaryio {
class BinaryReader {
    std::istream& is;

public:
    BinaryReader(std::istream& is) : is{is} {}
    BinaryReader(std::istream& is, endian byte_order)
        : is{is}, m_endian{byte_order} {}

    void seek(std::size_t offset,
              std::ios_base::seekdir seek_dir = std::ios_base::beg)
    {
        is.seekg(offset, seek_dir);
    }
    std::size_t tell() { return is.tellg(); }

    template <typename T>
    T read()
    requires (!std::is_pointer_v<T> && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
    {
        T val;
        _do_read(val);
        return val;
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> read_many(const std::size_t count)
    requires (!std::is_pointer_v<T> && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
    {
        std::vector<T> vals(count);
        _do_read(vals);
        return vals;
    }

    std::string
    read_string(const std::string::size_type max_len = std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string str;
        if (max_len == std::string::npos)
            return str;

        char arr[max_len];
        is.getline(arr, max_len, '\0');

        str = arr;

        return str;
    }

    endian endianness() const { return m_endian; }

    void set_endianness(endian new_endian) { m_endian = new_endian; }

    void swap_endianness()
    {
        if (m_endian == endian::big)
            m_endian = endian::little;
        else
            m_endian = endian::big;
    }

private:
    endian m_endian {endian::native};

    template <typename T>
    void _do_read(T& val)
    {
        if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof val))
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds read");

        swap_if_needed_in_place(val, m_endian);
    }

    template <class Range, typename T = typename Range::value_type>
    void _do_read(Range& vals)
    requires (std::ranges::output_range<Range, T>)
    {
        if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vals.data()), vals.size() * sizeof(T)))
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds read");

        for (auto& val : vals)
            swap_if_needed_in_place(val, m_endian);
    }
};
} // namespace binaryio
#endif
```

**binaryio/swap.h**

```
#include <bit>
#include <cstring>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#include "binaryio/type_utils.h"

#ifndef BINARYIO_SWAP_H
#define BINARYIO_SWAP_H

namespace binaryio {
using endian = std::endian;

// Bitswap the bytes of a value
template <typename T>
constexpr void swap(T& value)
{
    if (sizeof(T) == 1)
        return;

    std::array<char, sizeof(T)> data;
    std::memcpy(data.data(), &value, sizeof(T));

    for (int i{0}; i < sizeof(T)/2; ++i)
        std::swap(data[sizeof(T) - 1 - i], data[i]);

    std::memcpy(&value, data.data(), sizeof(T));
}

/// Swap a value if its endianness is not the same as the machine endianness.
/// @param endian  The endianness of the value.
template <typename T>
void swap_if_needed_in_place(T& value, endian endian)
{
    if (endian::native == endian)
        return;

    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>()) {
        swap(value);
    }

    if constexpr (exposes_fields<T>) {
        std::apply(
            [endian](auto&... fields) {
                (swap_if_needed_in_place(fields, endian), ...);
            },
            value.fields());
    }

    if constexpr (is_container<T>) {
        for (auto& val : value)
            swap(val);
    }
}

template <typename T>
T swap_if_needed(T value, endian endian)
{
    swap_if_needed_in_place(value, endian);
    return value;
}
} // namespace binaryio
#endif
```

**binaryio/type_utils.h**

```
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#ifndef BINARYIO_TYPE_UTILS_H
#define BINARYIO_TYPE_UTILS_H

namespace binaryio {

#define BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS(TYPE, ...)                                      \
    constexpr auto fields() { return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); }                  \
    constexpr auto fields() const { return std::tie(__VA_ARGS__); }            \

template <typename T>
concept exposes_fields = requires (T a)
{
    a.fields();
};

template <typename C>
concept is_container = requires (C a)
{
    C::value_type;
    C::reference;
    C::const_reference;
    C::iterator;
    C::const_iterator;
    C::difference_type;
    C::size_type;

    a.begin();
    a.end();
    a.cbegin();
    a.size();
    a.max_size();
    a.empty();
};

} // namespace binaryio
#endif
```

**binaryio/writer.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

#include "binaryio/swap.h"

#ifndef BINARYIO_WRITER_H
#define BINARYIO_WRITER_H

namespace binaryio {
class BinaryWriter {
    std::ostream& os;

public:
    // Based on
    // https://github.com/zeldamods/oead/blob/master/src/include/oead/util/binary_reader.h
    BinaryWriter(std::ostream& os, endian byte_order)
        : os{os}, m_endian{byte_order} {};

    void seek(std::size_t offset,
              std::ios_base::seekdir seek_dir = std::ios_base::beg)
    {
        os.seekp(offset, seek_dir);
    }
    std::size_t tell() { return os.tellp(); }

    template <typename T>
    void write(T value)
    requires (!std::is_pointer_v<T> && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
    {
        swap_if_needed_in_place(value, m_endian);
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
    }

    template <class Range, typename T = typename Range::value_type>
    void write_many(Range& values)
    requires (std::ranges::output_range<Range, T>)
    {
        for (auto& value : values)
            swap_if_needed_in_place(value, m_endian);

        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(values.begin().base()), values.size() * sizeof(T));
    }

    void write_string(std::string_view str)
    {
        os.write(str.data(), str.size());
    }

    endian endianness() { return m_endian; }

    void set_endianness(endian new_endian) { m_endian = new_endian; }

    void swap_endianness()
    {
        if (m_endian == endian::big)
            m_endian = endian::little;
        else
            m_endian = endian::big;
    }

private:
    endian m_endian{endian::native};
};
} // namespace binaryio

#endif
```

**Unit Test**

````
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "binaryio/reader.h"
#include "binaryio/writer.h"

struct FileHeader {
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t fileSize;
    BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS(FileHeader, magic, fileSize);
};

struct WaveFile {
    FileHeader riffHeader;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> magic;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> fmt;
    uint32_t fmtSize;
    uint16_t audioFormat;
    uint16_t numChannels;
    uint32_t sampleRate;
    uint32_t byteRate;
    uint16_t blockAlign;
    uint16_t bitsPerSample;
    uint8_t pad[0x8a];
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> dataMagic;
    uint32_t dataSize;
    // Data starts
    BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS(WaveFile, riffHeader, magic, fmt, fmtSize,
                           audioFormat, numChannels, sampleRate, byteRate,
                           blockAlign, bitsPerSample, dataMagic, dataSize);
} __attribute__((packed));

int main(int argc, char** argv)
try {
    // Read from the byte buffer
    std::ifstream ifs{argv[1]};
    binaryio::BinaryReader reader{ifs};
    WaveFile wav{reader.read<WaveFile>()};
    std::vector<char> data{reader.read_many<char>(wav.dataSize)};

    ifs.close();
    std::cout << "File 1 read" << '\n';

    // Print to stdout to see what was read
    std::cout << "Riff Magic: " << std::hex << wav.riffHeader.magic
              << '\n';
    std::cout << "Wave Magic: " << wav.magic.data() << '\n';

    // Write a new file
    std::ofstream ofs{"out_litte.wav"};
    binaryio::BinaryWriter writer{ofs, binaryio::endian::little};
    writer.write(wav);
    writer.write_many(data);
    ofs.close();
    std::cout << "File 2 written" << '\n';

    // Write a different file with its endianness swapped
    ofs.open("out_big.wav");
    writer.swap_endianness();
    writer.write(wav);
    writer.write_many(data);
    ofs.close();
    std::cout << "File 3 written" << '\n';

    // Read the new file, and compare the result with the original struct,
    // treating the new values as big endian, since endianness was swapped
    ifs.open("out_big.wav");
    if (reader.read<uint32_t>() == 0x52494646) {
        reader.swap_endianness();
        ifs.seekg(0);
    }
    WaveFile other_wav{reader.read<WaveFile>()};
    ifs.close();
    std::cout << "File 3 read" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Riff Magic: " << std::hex << other_wav.riffHeader.magic
              << '\n';
    std::cout << "Wave Magic: " << other_wav.magic.data() << '\n';

    if (wav.sampleRate == other_wav.sampleRate)
        std::cout << "Data preserved, endianness swapped" << std::endl;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Something went wrong and the data was changed");

    return 0;
} catch (std::runtime_error& err) {
    std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```
````

Comment: Interesting `require` is a pretty recent addition C++20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code Review:

Naming:

```
class BinaryReader {
    std::istream& is;

    // Lots of methods:

    endian m_endian {endian::native};
```

Personal opinion:
I like to group all the member variables together (for me this helps me make sure that I set all members in the constructor).

Another personal opinion:
I don't like your naming scheme. One variable is prefixed by `m_` but the other is simply the name (though a bit short - self documenting names is considered a good practice). Pick one style.

```
    BinaryReader(std::istream& is, endian byte_order)
        : is{is}, m_endian{byte_order} {}
```

Why is it called `byte_order` as a parameter and `m_endian` as a member? Seems a bit confusing.

---

Not sure I understand the logic of the default parameter here:

```
    std::string
    read_string(const std::string::size_type max_len = std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string str;
        if (max_len == std::string::npos)
            return str;
```

If you don't provide a parameter it simply returns a string?

---

This is technically not valid C++ (it's a common extension implemented by a lot of compilers):

```
        char arr[max_len];
```

Also you make a copy of the array in a couple of lines:

```
        str = arr;
```

Why not skip the copy? Create a string of the correct size and read directly into it.

```
       // Code does not include error check. Left as exercise.
       std::string  arr(max_len, '\0');
       is.getline(arr.data(), max_len, '\0');
       arr.resize(is.gcount());
```

---

You are using the wrong `Range` type here.

This is an input function so `std::ranges::output_range` is incorrect (it should be `std::ranges::input_range`).

```
template <class Range, typename T = typename Range::value_type>
void _do_read(Range& vals)
requires (std::ranges::output_range<Range, T>)
{
```

But `input_range` is still not correct. You are not using the `++` operator to move from one element to the next. You are assuming that all the elements are contiguous to each other. So you should be using `std::ranges::contiguous_range<T>`.

```
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vals.data()), vals.size() * sizeof(T)))
        throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds read");
```

---

Note this will only read `max_len-1` characters from the stream.

```
        is.getline(arr, max_len, '\0');
```

The last item in the array will be reserved for the null terminator.

---

Sure you can write it like this:

```
        if (m_endian == endian::big)
            m_endian = endian::little;
        else
            m_endian = endian::big;
```

Personally, I would do it as:

```
        m_endian = (m_endian == endian::big) ? endian::little : endian::big;
```

---

You copy the data to and from a buffer. Why not swap in place?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr void swap(T& value)
{
    if (sizeof(T) == 1)
        return;

    std::array<char, sizeof(T)> data;
    std::memcpy(data.data(), &value, sizeof(T));

    for (int i{0}; i < sizeof(T)/2; ++i)
        std::swap(data[sizeof(T) - 1 - i], data[i]);

    std::memcpy(&value, data.data(), sizeof(T));
}
```

I would simply do this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr void swap(T& value)
{
    char* data  = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value);

    for (int i{0}; i < sizeof(T)/2; ++i)
        std::swap(data[sizeof(T) - 1 - i], data[i]);
}
```

---

This is line is currently beyond me :-)
I need to study but assume it is OK.

```
    if constexpr (exposes_fields<T>) {
        std::apply(
            [endian](auto&... fields) {
                (swap_if_needed_in_place(fields, endian), ...);
            },
            value.fields());
    }
```

---

To prevent a copy, pass by reference and return the reference.

```
template <typename T>
T swap_if_needed(T value, endian endian)
{
    swap_if_needed_in_place(value, endian);
    return value;
}
```

---

Hold on. In the read version don't you look for a terminating `\0` character? In this case you should write that `\0` character to the output stream.

```
    void write_string(std::string_view str)
    {
        os.write(str.data(), str.size());  // You need + 1 on the size.
    }
```

---